# Git. Change repository root folder

Tags: git

I have my project in folder `C:/projects/NameOfProject/MyCode/`, and `.git` is located in folder `MyCode/`, so only MyCode's contents are in repository.

Recently I added some other files that are in the folder `OtherFiles/` related to the project in folder `NameOfProject/`. I can't move these to `MyCode/` due to relationship between files in `MyCode/` and `OtherFiles/`. And now I need to change repository settings somehow, the folders `MyCode/` and `OtherFiles/` will be located at the root of repository. And moreover, it's highly desirable to continue commit history: next commit after changing root of repository will keep on the history of the current branch.

To summarize the above: I have repo in `C:/projects/NameOfProject/MyCode/` and I want to move repo root to `C:/projects/NameOfProject/` not moving files/subfolders in both of these folders.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to rewrite directory names in the entire `NameOfProject/MyCode/` repository using `git filter-branch`. I recommend to it this way:

1. Backup everything.
2. Copy directory `MyCode` to a temporary location.
3. (In that temp dir) rewrite directories with the command:
   `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mkdir MyCode && mv * MyCode || :' -- --all`. The filter will rewrite all branches; for every existing commit it creates a new subdirectory `MyCode` and moves all files into it (ignoring errors; there will be at least one error — cannot mv `MyCode` into `MyCode`). This is the main part of the entire process; it prepares the repository to expect all files in subdirectory `MyCode` instead of the root of the repository but preserves the commit history.
4. Move the new `.git` directory to `C:/projects/NameOfProject/` (not to `MyCode`!) and cleanup temp dir.
5. Verify you have a backup and remove `MyCode/.git`.
6. `git add OtherFiles`
7. `git commit -m OtherFiles`

Comment: Looks like the solution. I'll try it soon

Comment: Thanks @phd. I am not aware about this filter command till now. Thanks for sharing it. It is really worth to know and will try this solution and come back.

Comment: `git filter-branch` is hard to use and `--tree-filter` is rather slow (it extracts all files *for every commit* it processes and then creates a new commit from the new tree) but it's quite powerful command.

Comment: @phd it works. I had some difficulties with `refs/original/refs/remotes` after your solution, but in overal it works. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize a new repo under C:/projects/NameOfProject/ by

> git init

and pull the remote branch under that repo and just copy and replace those two folders MyCode and OtherFiles into initialized git repo and push it to your remote.

Comment: But will this save his commit history for `MyCode`?

Comment: Yes of course. Because we pull the remote branch to this repo.

Comment: That will not work. If you pull `C:/projects/NameOfProject/MyCode/` into `C:/projects/NameOfProject/` git just would copy files from `NameOfProject/MyCode/` to `NameOfProject/` thus muddying the entire `NameOfProject/`. You need to rewrite directory names in the entire `NameOfProject/MyCode/` repository.